# How to automatically resize mkmapview to fill entire screen on orientation change?

Tags: ios, resize, mkmapview, orientation, mapkit

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    self.mapView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D startCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.7472, -95.9594);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(startCoord, 10000*1609.344, 10000*1609.344)];
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
}
```

That's the code I have right now.  When I change the orientation of my iPad from landscape to portrait, the map view's size doesn't change.  I would like it to fill the entire view.  I have tried searching google and stackoverflow for a solution, but I haven't had any luck.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.mapView.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

This will ensure that the map frame will adjust to the view bounds whenever the view controller layout is triggered (like, on autorotation).

You can actually take the set frame line out of viewWillAppear, since viewWillLayoutSubviews runs at initial setup time.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?  I assumed you weren't since you were setting the frame manually, but maybe you are and that initial frame set has no effect. That would stop any further manual layout from working too. Also try putting a breakpoint on viewWillLayoutSubviews and see if it's even running, and if self.mapView is non-nil.

Comment: thanks jsd! autoresizingMasks were SO slow, this worked wonders.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Autolayout, you can:
- go to the Storyboard, then click on your mapView.
- look for a segmented control on the bottom of Storyboard and click the segment "Pin" .There, add the constrains for left, right, up and down. This should do what you want.

Very simple and no code required.